# Как кастомизировать ActionBar?

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Нужно отрисовать следующий интерфейс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для начала пытаюсь заменить стиль ActionBar'а

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

actionbar_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/background">
    </solid>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp">
    </corners>
</shape>
```

Однако внешний вид не меняется. Что делаю не так? Может дело в `parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar"`? Наследоваться от чего то другого?

И второй вопрос по поводу карточки в стиле Material design. Думаю попробовать реализовать ее с помощью RecyclerView или есть какой то более подходящий способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал таким образом

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/logo</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/background</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, по поводу actionBar: можно сделать данный виджет с кастомной разметкой у которой будут все необходимые вам свойства. Стиль здесь не особо поможет как мне кажется. [Вот](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-custom-actionbar-in-android) например есть туториал как сделать тулбар с своим макетом. Ключевым здесь является установка созданного xml макета в тулбар:

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
View view = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
```

И [вот](https://www.journaldev.com/9952/android-custom-action-bar-example-tutorial) еще один подобный туториал. Во-вторых по поводу карточки: это обычный cardView внутри которого можно разместить вертикальный LinearLayout с виджетами. В данном случае recyclerView будет слишком громоздким и он вообще для таких целей не используется. Только вам кроме создания самой карточки нужно будет установить ее выше чем ваш кастомный тулбар как у вас показано на картинке. Вот пример такой карточки:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

 // здесь нужно разместить ваши поля для ввода
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792826/how-to-properly-put-a-layout-into-a-cardview) есть подобное обсуждение и [туториал](https://mobikul.com/designing-layout-using-cardview/).